# Including another div in a flex grow box and containing it within the parent div

Tags: html, css

First things first, a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2v1axtkz/3/

I have a flex grow box with a floating right image and am trying to add underneath a text box and contain them both within the parent box.

Reason for this is that there is an `onclick` event for the parent box, so I need both the image box and the text box contained within the same parent.

Right now it's not happening and I can't figure out why.

The markup is:

```
<div class="sections__container__outside" onclick="action();">
  <div class="sections__container__box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="sections__container__box__title">Title</div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the image, the text is somehow outside the parent container even though it's inside of the div:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `height: 100%` on the `.sections__container__box`. That essentially pushes out the title container. I'm assuming you want the red in the background, so just removing that won't work.

You need to remove the `float` from the image and make that `.sections__container__box` display flex and then use the `justify-content` property to position the image.

```css
.sections__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 630px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sections__container__box {
  background-color: #FF0030;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sections__container__outside {
  width: 40%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
}

.sections__container__box__title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections__container">

  <div class="sections__container__outside" onclick="action();">
    <div class="sections__container__box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="sections__container__box__title">Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sections__container__outside" onclick="action();">
    <div class="sections__container__box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="sections__container__box__title">Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sections__container__outside" onclick="action();">
    <div class="sections__container__box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="sections__container__box__title">Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sections__container__outside" onclick="action();">
    <div class="sections__container__box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="sections__container__box__title">Title</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was missing the `flex-end` part. Something new learned. Thank you! :)